# Ubuntu tweak does not start (Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library)

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I recently reinstalled my Ubuntu 12.04. The main idea was to not disturb files on /home, and I succeeded by reinstalling Ubuntu only on / partition.

When I got back I found everything working but not ubuntu-tweak. I have found many advices such as reinstalling "compiz" or adding older repositories bot none have worked.

When I start ubuntu-tweak in terminal I receive long bundle of code which I don't really understand. I feel it would say important things but I just can not read it properly.

I simply love ubuntu-tweak software and I would like to have it up and running just as before system swap.

There is my problem :

```
fahrenheit@fahrenheit-1225C:~$ ubuntu-tweak
(ubuntu-tweak:3173): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak", line 122, in <module>
from ubuntutweak.main import UbuntuTweakWindow
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/main.py", line 40, in <module>
from ubuntutweak.preferences import PreferencesDialog
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/preferences.py", line 32, in <module>
from ubuntutweak.factory import WidgetFactory
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/factory.py", line 24, in <module>
from ubuntutweak.gui.widgets import *
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/gui/widgets.py", line 10, in <module>
from ubuntutweak.settings.compizsettings import CompizSetting
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/compizsettings.py", line 3, in <module>
import ccm
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from Conflicts import *
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 25, in <module>
from Constants import *
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntutweak/settings/ccm/Constants.py", line 77, in <module>
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/359932/127327) may help you.

Comment: Thank you souravc3, you are THE MAN! It worked! :D It did not exactly helped my case but obviously focused me on matter of language issue. I solved it by updating language manager in system settings and toped English language at the top of the list. Suddenly ubuntu-tweak started to run as it should :) Tank you so much and I would like to thank someone who edited my question so neatly as I would like to post it. I would mark the problem solved but I don't really know how ;P

Comment: nice to see that your problem is solved. you can write the answer by yourself stating how you solved the issue and accept it. See [self-answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install locales
```

and the famous:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This rids the system of locales, then re-installs locales and downgrades libc6 from 2.19 to 2.13 which is the issue. Then configures locales again.