# Playonlinux not working

Tags: playonlinux

After a couple of months of not using and installing the 17.10 playonlinux will not let me install a game I was able to install and play a couple of months ago. At each start up I get these errors:

```
:~$ playonlinux
Looking for python... 2.7.14 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.12) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: check_dd_x86 missing, test skipped
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: check_dd_amd64 missing, test skipped
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/samuel/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
wget-log: Permission denied; disabling logging.
```

The "wget-log" line repeats at least 20 times afterwards. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Remove all of PlayOnLinux and install the `wine` command that is a great alternative to install and run any Windows app, here is my explanation : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

### There is problem with pacpate "Locale"

Reconfigure it and try again

Try running dat 4 reconfiguration languages

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359753/gtk-warning-locale-not-supported-by-c-library-when-starting-apps-from-th)

---

It Worked for me soo i hope it will work for you too