# How do I connect to VNC?

Tags: vnc

I have a google cloud instance, I installed xfce, installed and configured VNC Server using this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

Now I'm in this step:
Next, you may now use a VNC client to attempt a connection to the VNC server at localhost:5901. You'll be prompted to authenticate.

What's that VNC client and how do I connect it to the VNC server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Remmina](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Remmina) VNC client for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

I prefer [Vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre):

```
sudo apt install vinagre
```

For more examples, see https://www.ubuntupit.com/10-fast-and-secure-remote-desktop-client-software-for-linux/

Comment: I installed Remmina for Debian using this link: https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/#

Comment: When I call Remmina I get:
(org.remmina.Remmina:25371): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.remmina.Remmina:25371): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: I found this page: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/359753/gtk-warning-locale-not-supported-by-c-library-when-starting-apps-from-th

After this command:
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base

I get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en-base

Comment: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you just try `sudo apt install remmina`?

Comment: I just did and got the same error: (org.remmina.Remmina:25665): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.remmina.Remmina:25665): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: @Niminim Have you removed the Debian version before installing the Ubuntu one?

Comment: @Melebius I used the three code lines from here (for Debian):
https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/#

Comment: @Niminim And have you _removed_ it then? If not, it might still get launched instead of the Ubuntu version you installed later. If you executed those Debian commands, do not forget to remove the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list` and run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: That's all I did, later I tried sudo apt install remmina. I don't think that any of the lines remove anything.

Comment: @Melebius I get:
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list: Permission denied

Comment: @Melebius , I used the  line you wrote: "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list"

Comment: Please, _never_ blindly execute code from the web without understanding the context. “Remove the file blabla” is very different from “run blabla”.

Comment: It looks like the problem has something to do with language settings.

Comment: I tried rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list , I get: rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list': Permission denied

Comment: Anyway, it looks like the problem has something to do with language settings, maybe if we solve that it won't be necessary  to remove the Ubuntu version.

Comment: I find the locale problem just a sign of the installed Debian binary being incompatible with your system. I’d prefer to remove the Debian repository (to prevent installing other such binaries in the future) and install the Ubuntu version. If you want us to help you with that, please [start a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) containing the information you’ve posted here in comments.